# Why does pandas insist on converting my object columns to datetimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am pulling data from an IBM DB2 data source that has nothing but string fields. Some of those fields contain timestamps but they are string datatypes because there are timestamps like '0001-01-01 00:00:00'. I check the df.dtypes and everything is an object. When I try to write the dataframe via pandas.to_sql() with a sqlalchemy engine to a microsoft sql table (I drop the table and let sqlalchemy create it brand new from the dataframe) I get an error that makes it seem like pandas is trying to convert the timestamp fields to datetimes rather than leaving them as strings/objects. What am I missing?

The dataframe:

```
BIL_DIV_NO         object
CAS_UPC_NO         object
CAT_ID             object
CAT_PPS_ID         object
CAT_ITM_NO         object
SRC_ID             object
UNT_FTR_AM         object
UNT_PRC_SIZ_CD     object
CAT_ADD_DT         object
CAT_END_DT         object
CON_UPC_NO         object
UNT_OVD_CD         object
UNT_LBL_QY         object
SPS_RTL_FL         object
ROW_UPD_TS         object
DIV_CAS_STU_CD     object
CAT_PPS_001_ID     object
CAT_ITM_001_NO     object
ROW_UPD_001_TS     object
MAX_ORD_ITM_QY     object
SKU_NO             object
FAM_DPT_CD         object
FAM_CLS_CD         object
FAM_SBC_CD         object
TSK_ID             object
CRE_ID             object
LST_UPD_ID         object
LIS_CST_AM         object
DIV_ACT_NO         object
LIN_NO             object
DIV_COM_CD         object
DIV_DPT_CD         object
DIV_INF_CD         object
PRC_BOK_CD         object
QPS_SIZ_TX         object
QPS_DSC_TX         object
ALT_DPT_CD         object
QPS_SCN_CD         object
RCM_FL             object
ORL_DIV_COM_CD     object
ORL_DIV_DPT_CD     object
PDT_ANA_CD         object
SCH_CGY_CD         object
CLB_PAK_FL         object
CMR_CD             object
CRV_AM             object
RLN_TYP_CD         object
RLT_CON_UPC_NO     object
DEP_LNK_CD         object
SCH_CLS_CD         object
MRC_FL             object
dtype: object
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db
import urllib
import datetime
import time
import math
import sqlalchemy as sa

whs_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT SRC_ID FROM {}.{} FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR;".format(db2_schema, table_name)

db2_conn = db.connect(
    driver=db2_driver,
    hostname=db2_server,
    database=db2_database,
    uid=db2_username,
    pwd=db2_password,
    protocol=db2_protocol,
    port=db2_port,
    autocommit=True
)

whs_nos = pd.read_sql(whs_sql, db2_conn)['SRC_ID'].values.tolist()

db2_conn.close()

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % sca_params, fast_executemany=True)
engine.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute("DROP TABLE {}.{}.{}".format(sca_sql_database, sca_sql_schema, table_name))
engine.dispose()

for whs_no in whs_nos:
    db2_sql = """
        SELECT
            *            
        FROM {}.{} WHERE SRC_ID = '{}'
        FOR FETCH ONLY
        WITH UR;
    """.format(db2_schema, table_name, whs_no)

    db2_conn = db.connect(
        driver=db2_driver,
        hostname=db2_server,
        database=db2_database,
        uid=db2_username,
        pwd=db2_password,
        protocol=db2_protocol,
        port=db2_port,
        autocommit=True
    )

    df = pd.read_sql(db2_sql, db2_conn)

    db2_conn.close()

    engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % sca_params, fast_executemany=True)

    df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, schema=sca_sql_schema)

    engine.dispose()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1858, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 198, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python_Scripts/EXT_TBL_DMPS/PIDORDEN.py", line 138, in <module>
    df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, schema=sca_sql_schema)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2663, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 521, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1314, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 622, in __init__
    self.table = self._create_table_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 868, in _create_table_setup
    column_names_and_types = self._get_column_names_and_types(self._sqlalchemy_type)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 860, in _get_column_names_and_types
    for i in range(len(self.frame.columns))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 860, in <listcomp>
    for i in range(len(self.frame.columns))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 970, in _sqlalchemy_type
    if col.dt.tz is not None:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 85, in _getter
    return self._delegate_property_get(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 62, in _delegate_property_get
    values = self._get_values()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 53, in _get_values
    return DatetimeIndex(data, copy=False, name=self.name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 253, in __new__
    ambiguous=ambiguous,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 320, in _from_sequence
    ambiguous=ambiguous,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1755, in sequence_to_dt64ns
    data, dayfirst=dayfirst, yearfirst=yearfirst
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1863, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1854, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 481, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 698, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 694, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 566, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: have you tried setting the `dtype` option in `df.to_sql()` to object?

Comment: ah damnit @TiTo... can't believe I missed that. Still learning on the job I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so big thanks to TiTo for the comment. The answer is to set the dtype option in df.to_sql()  Gosh I feel dumb. HAHA. THANKS!!

```
df.to_sql(table_name,
          engine,
          if_exists='append',
          index=False,
          schema=sca_sql_schema,
          dtype={'CAT_ADD_DT': sa.String,
                 'CAT_END_DT': sa.String,
                 'ROW_UPD_TS': sa.String,
                 'ROW_UPD_001_TS': sa.String})
```